# counting words that begin with a given substring

Tags: javascript, string

I am trying to find the count of words in a given string that start with a particular substring, without prototype:

```
myString="cat car cab. came, corn ";
substring = "ca";
count =0;
if (myString.match(substring))
   count++;

return count;
```

My expected result is 4.

Comment: Can you add an example?

Comment: myString="cat car cab. came, corn " and substring is "ca" then the occurence of that in the whole string is 4

Comment: And a substring of... ?

Comment: And what is the count you want?

Comment: substring will be given in the function's parameter, "substring" is the actual substring in my code

Answer (score 2):

You can use `regex`:

```
var myString = 'cat car cab. came, corn ';
alert(myString.match(/\s?(ca\w*)/g).length)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use match with a global regex and examine the length of the returned :array

```js
function countWordsWithSubstring(sentence, substring) {
  var matches = sentence.match(new RegExp('\\b' + substring, 'g'));
  return matches ? matches.length : 0;
}
                                 
var myString="cacat acaacacar cab. came, corn ";
alert(countWordsWithSubstring(myString, 'ca'));
```

Comment: Try with `var myString="cat car cab. came, corn cacaca ";`

Comment: Your code will give 6 with `cat car cabca. came, cornca ` and you anly need words that starts from 'ca'.

Comment: What if I try this: var count = (myString.match("/substring/g") ).length;

Answer (score 0):

Will use Regex to match words in string, Regex will result an array of matched words, as an Example:

```
string = "car cat caw ctt" 
subString = "ca"

string.match(new RegExp('\\b' + subString, 'g'))  // will reult ["ca", "ca", "ca"]
```

and in case no match will return null and that's why we have || to return an empty array

```
a = null || [] // this will return []
```

and for the resulted array will check the length and return.

```
  function countWordsBeginningWith(subString, myString){

     var count = (myString.match(new RegExp('\\b' + subString, 'g')) || 
     []).length;

    return count;       
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you should [edit] your answer to include a description why this answers the question. By adding a description you help readers understand the intricacies of the solution and prevent them from making the same mistake twice.